# If every subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that "If every **finite** subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is independent" is true. In fact, every textbook proves this statement. But why not "If every subset(**either finite or infinite**) of $S$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is independent"

To me, there seems to be no problem at all.

Comment: In general, there are not infinite sums defined in a vector space.

Comment: Since $S$ is a subset of $S$, this is true, too. Perhaps you mean proper subset?

Comment: #Clocktower Whether a set S is linearly independent or not has nothing to do witn infinieness of the set S

Comment: If every subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then every finite subset of $S$ is independent, and hence, by the result you just cited, $S$ is independent.

Comment: #Thomas yes any proper subset of s

Comment: #Thomas But i want to know when every infinite subset of S which is larger than finite set of S is linearly independent

Comment: That's not the question you asked. You asked if all subsets (infinite and finite) were independent.

Comment: No thats the assumption. I want to prove whether S is linearly independent given the assumptions.

Comment: To prove a possibly infinite set  S is linearly independent, you will have to take finite linear combinations of elements from S

Answer (score 1):

Given a subset $S$ of a vector space, the following are equivalent.

1. Every subset of $S$ is linearly independent
2. $S$ is linearly independent
3. Every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent

> **Proof:** You stated that (2) is equivalent to (3) in your question, so let us believe this.
>
> Obviously (1) implies (3), if something holds for all subsets, then it holds for all finite subsets.
>
> Now suppose (2) and (3) hold and let $T$ be some subset of $S$. We want to show $T$ is linearly independent. We know it is enough to show that every finite subset of $T$ is linearly independent. However, if $F$ is a finite subset of $T$, then $F$ is also a finite subset of $S$, and so $F$ is linearly independent because $S$ is, and we have proven $T$ is linearly independent, i.e. (1) holds.

When $S$ is itself a finite set, these are not equivalent to

4. Every proper subset of $S$ is linearly independent.

Consider, for instance $\{1,2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, where we view $\mathbb{R}$ as a 1-dimensional real vector space. Observe, every proper subset of $S$ is linearly independent, but $S$ itself is not.