# Let $S$ be a set of vectors. If each finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's a similar question which doesn't answer mine:

[If every subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641227/if-every-subset-of-s-is-linearly-independent-then-s-is-independent)

Let $S$ be finite. Let $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \ldots \cup S_n = S$ such that $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \ldots \cap S_n = \emptyset.$ Let $S_i = \{v_1, \ldots,v_n\}.$ Then if $a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n = 0$, then $a_i = 0$ for all $i.$ So, the union of all $S_i$ contains $\{u_1,\ldots, u_n\}$ such that $b_1u_1 + \ldots + b_nu_n = 0$ with $b_i = 0$ for any $i.$ Does it work for finite $S$?

Comment: The definition of linear independence of $S$ is that whenever $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ are $ n$ distinct members of $S,$  then $\sum_1^n a_i v_i=0 \iff \{a_i,...,a_n\}=\{0\}.$  Thus  $S$ is linearly independent iff every finite subset of $  S$ is linearly independent. Regardless of whether $S$ is or isn't finite.

Comment: @ user254665 Here's a [screenshot](http://s33.postimg.org/t2mjaco1b/image.png) of my problem. One direction is easy because of [this theorem](http://s33.postimg.org/hzs8jtmwf/image.png). Maybe they want us to be more explicit?